# sql depth selection give no solution

Tags: sql, oracle

I must modify a sql statement on my work for an altered data information.

This is the old one code:

```
SELECT count(*) n,  max(pce.insert_ts) last_insert, pce.p_code, dpc.m_operation
from tcp_data.fw_p_erg pce inner join tcp_data.fw_dim_p_code dpc
                                       on (pce.p_code = dpc.p_code)
where dpc.show_class = 22
  and pce.p_code not in ('42282221')
group by pce.p_code, dpc.m_operation
order by last_insert desc, n desc, p_code
;
```

The modification is to exclude more data from this selection.
I have some p_code combination under 1 tpc_id.
This tpc_id is for one process but have more line in DB with more tpc_ids.

The exist sql statement show all exist data for existing show class level 22 and p_codes are not in '42282221'.
But I must exclude all p_code '46262255' 
 combined with '23040400', '23040401', '23040411', '23040412', '23040414', '23040496', '23040497' (under one tpc_id)
and 
p_code '42282241' combined with 
'21041019', '21041015', '21041024'.

So I test with this statement:

```
SELECT count(*) n,  max(pce.insert_ts) last_insert, pce.p_code, dpc.m_operation
from tcp_data.fw_p_erg xce,
     tcp_data.fw_p_erg pce inner join tcp_data.fw_dim_p_code dpc
                                   on (pce.p_code = dpc.p_code)
where dpc.show_class = 22
  and pce.p_code not in ('42282221')
  and not(xce.tcp_id=pce.tcp_id an xce.p_code = '46262255' and pce.p_code not in ('23040400', '23040401', '23040411', '23040412', '23040414', '23040496', '23040497'))
  and not(xce.tcp_id=pce.tcp_id an xce.p_code = '42282241' and pce.p_code not in ('21041019', '21041015', '21041024'))
group by pce.p_code, dpc.m_operation
order by last_insert desc, n desc, p_code
;
```

But it doesnt work.
I get only an empty table back. Have someone any idea why and how i can solve it ?

Comment: That is strange. I would have expected the statement to return an awful lot of records. You are doing a cross join and hardly exclude any records afterwards.

Comment: To me it seems you are trying to find out if some records exist or not exist. An EXISTS clause would hence seem appropriate.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner:
The problem is, all data exist only on 1 table. (2nd one is only needed for show class). In the main table i have the tcp_id's which describe an operation order. One orde have any p_codes which describe cases and/or calls from system.
My sql statement would give an overview about some causes from complete data.
I need all stuff in show_class level 22. No entry has p_code '42282221'.
But i need more exclusion. Example:
tcp_id = 50 - p_code = '46262255';
tcp_id = 50 - p_code = '23040400';
tcp_id = 50 - p_code = '23040439';

Comment: @ThorstenKettner:
My statement count all entry, but i dont need the line "tcp_id = 50 - p_code = '23040400'" in compine with "tcp_id = 50 - p_code = '46262255'". I dont need these combinations in my count overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your last comments, especially the last one on Hennes' answer, it seems obvious that you are looking for the EXISTS clause, which was what I assumed from the start. So please check, if the following query works for you.

```
SELECT 
  count(*) n,
  max(pce.insert_ts) last_insert, 
  pce.p_code, 
  dpc.m_operation
from tcp_data.fw_p_erg pce 
inner join tcp_data.fw_dim_p_code dpc on (pce.p_code = dpc.p_code)
where dpc.show_class = 22
  and pce.p_code not in ('42282221')
  and not
  (
    pce.p_code in ('23040400', '23040401', '23040411', '23040412', '23040414', '23040496', '23040497')
    and 
    exists (select * from tcp_data.fw_p_erg xce where xce.tcp_id = pce.tcp_id and xce.p_code = '46262255')
  )
  and not
  (
    pce.p_code in ('21041019', '21041015', '21041024')
    and 
    exists (select * from tcp_data.fw_p_erg xce where xce.tcp_id = pce.tcp_id and xce.p_code = '42282241')
  )
group by pce.p_code, dpc.m_operation
order by last_insert desc, n desc, p_code
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your 'excists' view helps me to solve my problem. With this i can find a technical fault and fix it. But all in all that was the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you included the table fw_p_erg twice and combine them on their id. Err, what ist that for?? Is that a typo?

Nevertheless, the join xce.tcp_id=pce.tcp_id should be outside the brackets like this:

```
SELECT count(*) n,  max(pce.insert_ts) last_insert, pce.p_code, dpc.m_operation
from tcp_data.fw_p_erg xce,
    tcp_data.fw_p_erg pce inner join tcp_data.fw_dim_p_code dpc
                               on (pce.p_code = dpc.p_code)
where dpc.show_class = 22
  and pce.p_code not in ('42282221')
  and xce.tcp_id=pce.tcp_id
  and not(xce.p_code = '46262255' and pce.p_code not in ('23040400',     '23040401', '23040411', '23040412', '23040414', '23040496', '23040497'))
  and not(xce.p_code = '42282241' and pce.p_code not in ('21041019', '21041015', '21041024'))
group by pce.p_code, dpc.m_operation
order by last_insert desc, n desc, p_code
;
```

Hennes

Comment: My idea for this wasnt a rly combine,i need the id as compare part. It gives any line with 1 same id numer (this id describe an operation order) and on this 1 id it gaves any p_codes, which describe an order or system call.
My count overview list some cases and give a review of some problems.

It give some combination their doesnt needed.

Comment: Example: id = 50
1 line with id = 50 have p_code=46262255
if this code exist and give one line under this (at example)
id = 50 and p_code=23040400, this lane must be ignore on my count, because the error order 23040400 in combine with call number (p_code =46262255) its not important for the overview.

I hope my problem is better described now.